# ¿Tener una memoria SSD afecta de alguna forma el tiempo de ejecución de mis programas? Pregunto especialmente por programas en Visual Studio/C++

Tags: visual-studio, windows

Estoy realizando una comparativa del tiempo de ejecución en diversos programas y quisiera tener en cuenta todos los factores que pueden hacer variar el criterio elegido.

Comment: Depende: Una SSD es *mucho* más rápida que un HDD tradicional. Si tu aplicación requiere mucho uso de escritura/lectura de datos, entonces se verá afectada. Por ejemplo, un navegador consume datos de la red y apenas notarás la diferencia entre arrancarlo desde una u otra unidad.

Comment: En caso de que no se carguen datos, sino los inicialice en el mismo código (cientos de ellos), ¿eso se ve afectado por la SSD?

Comment: Aportando algo más de información... La RAM que tengas también tiene importancia, ya no tanto el almacenamiento que tengas (x GB), sino la tecnología que emplee. No es lo mismo tener una DDR que una DDR4. Muchos IDEs emplean la RAM a la hora de ejecutar programas

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Vamos a suponer que tienes un martillo y un cincel, con esas herramientas escribes una suma en una losa de piedra:

> 2 + 2

Acto seguido usas un bolígrafo para escribir la misma suma en un post-it™

> 2 + 2

Ahora llamas a un amigo y le pides que haga la suma. ¿Ha tardado más en hacer la operación de la losa de piedra o la operación del post-it™?

---

El medio en que se guarde un ejecutable no afecta a su velocidad de ejecución.